# Meaning of 'bimensual'

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones

The [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/bimensual) translates "**bimensual**" as

> - (= **cada dos meses**) "bimonthly", "two-monthly"
> - (= **dos veces al mes**) "fortnightly", "semimonthly (US)"

How can this be?
Is it 'cada dos meses' (**6** times a year) or 'dos veces al mes' (**24** times a year)?
Is there an error in the dictionary?

Comment: What sounds strange to you?

The preffix "bi" referred to the number two, "mensual" is directly translated to "monthly".

So, one time each two months... what's the problem?

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't notice that. Yes, it's a tricky one but it's correct, a matter of context. In fact I think it's much more common to use it for the "6 times a year" meaning, but I'm not sure enough of it to put it in an answer.

Comment: Another example, [trimensual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=afHok4T) and [trimestral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=afXyw0a). Pay attention on the meaning of the ending **-mestral** in other examples such as [cuatrimestral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BUvA8Cl) and [semestral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XWEwl8y).

Comment: Seems many people confuse semiannual and biannual in the US as well.  So I can understand such a mistake when most translation dictionaries seem to not receive quite the same attention as primary dictionaries.  Perhaps it even can work in those different ways in different regions (I sure hope not!)

Answer (score 8):

According to the DRAE there is no possible confusion:

> **[bimensual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5WxK8ux)**
>
> De *bi-* y *mensual*.
>
> 1. adj. Que se hace u ocurre dos veces al mes.
>
> **[bimestral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5X2adpY)**
>
> 1. adj. Que sucede o se repite cada bimestre.

So *bimensual* is just twice a month, and *bimestral* is once every two months.

You could also use

> **[quincenal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UssTNib)**
>
> 1. adj. Que sucede o se repite cada quincena.

as a synonym-ish (there can be a slight difference) of *bimensual*.

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes.